# Simplify plot() code in R

Tags: r, plot

When I add multiiple lines to a plot the code blows up like this.

```
plot_pch = 16
plot_ltya = 'solid'
plot_ltyb = 'dotted'

plot(df[cond1, 'field'], 
     type='o',
     pch=plot_pch,
     plot_ltya)
lines(df[cond2, 'field'],
      type='o',      
      pch=plot_pch,
      lty=plot_ltya)
lines(df[cond3, 'field'],
      type='o',      
      pch=plot_pch,
      lty=plot_ltya)
lines(df[cond4, 'field'],
      type='o',      
      pch=plot_pch,
      lty=plot_ltyb)
lines(df[cond5, 'field'],
      type='o',      
      pch=plot_pch,
      lty=plot_ltyb)
```

Is there a way to simplyfy that with kind of global settings?

```
setglobal(pch=plot_pch)
```

Comment: `par()$pch`, check out `?par()`

Comment: There are a number of ways this could be made more efficient, but it's hard to recommend the right solution without knowing a little more. What do your data actually look like? What do these plotting commands currently produce?

Comment: @bouncyball Please transform this to an answer. This is exactly what I meant! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change a graphical parameter (like `pch`) for the remainder of an `R` session you can do the following:

```
plot_pch <- 16
par(pch = plot_pch)
```

After setting the `pch` value, another way to simplify this call would be to use the `mapply` function:

```
plot(df[cond1, 'field'], 
     type='o',
     pch=plot_pch,
     lty = 'solid')

mapply(function(df, lty) lines(df, type = 'o', lty = lty), 
df = list(df[cond2, 'field'], df[cond3, 'field'], 
          df[cond4, 'field'], df[cond5, 'field']), 
lty = rep(c('solid','dotted'), each = 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

you could make your own function

```
mylines <- function(cond){
   lines(df[cond, 'field'],
   type='o',
   pch=plot_pch,
   lty=plot_ltya)
}

plot(df[cond1, 'field'], 
     type='o',
     pch=plot_pch,
     lty=plot_ltya)
mylines(cond2)
mylines(cond3)
```

etc